# How to draw a Moving arrow image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have to draw a moving Arrow image (using C# code VS2008) between 2 Bars (image). I tried it with two approaches:

1. Draw arrow figure by joining points. and then keep changing the x,y coordinates.
2. making an arrow image and then keep changing its position.

The issue is flickering. Whenever I move the arrow image (or redraw the points) nearby images (actually there few other images as Bars are there) flickers. I tried to call invalidate(rect) thinking it will redraw the given rectangle only but still as soon the arrow image crosses these bars, everything flickers. which doesn't look good. how can I move this arrow image in a smooth fashion. Pls. suggest. Or should I adopt another approach?

// Code: **

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap bitmapAntenna;
    private Bitmap bitmapArrow;

```
public Form1()
{
    bitmapAntenna = new Bitmap("D:\\AntennaBar.JPG");
    bitmapArrow = new Bitmap("D:\\Arrow.JPG");
}

private void DrawAntennaImages(int antennaNo)
{
    Graphics grph = this.CreateGraphics();
    if (1 == antennaNo)
    {
        grph.DrawImage(bitmapAntenna, new RectangleF(350, 300, bitmapAntenna.Width*(1.00F), bitmapAntenna.Height*(1.00F))) ;
    }
    else
        grph.DrawImage(AntennaImage, new Point(550, 300));
}

private void DrawArrowImages(int X)
{
    Graphics grph = this.CreateGraphics();
    grph.DrawImage(bitmapArrow, new Point(380 + X, 350));
}

private void PaintHandler(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawAntennaImages(1);
    DrawAntennaImages(2);
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
    {
        //  Note: first draw antenna 1 image, arrow image then antenna 2 image so that arrow will overlap
        //  only antenna 1 image only.

        DrawAntennaImages(1);       //  Draw Antenn 1 image
        DrawArrowImages(i * 2);     //  Draw Arrow image
        DrawAntennaImages(2);       //  Draw Antenn 2 image

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);  //  Sleep before drawing next time ..
    }
    this.Invalidate(); // If I don't call this, arrow image does not elope after last draw
}
```

}

// In designer

this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.PaintHandler);

//Code ***

Thanks
RPS

Comment: Please tag your question with either WinForms or WPF

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming WinForms here:

Have you tried using [double buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering)?

You could try to [implement your own double buffering](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-tutorial-manage-your-own-double-buffering).

Do not expect miracles here; WinForms was never meant to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on double buffering for the form

```
myCanvasForm.SetStyle(
  ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
  ControlStyles.UserPaint |
  ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer,true);
```

or for the control you draw on.

```
myCanvasControl.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

[Here is some more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx) about double buffering in windows forms and GDI+.

Oh, and by the way: These kind of problems do not exist in [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms754130.aspx). When it comes to graphics quality and ease of use (for straightforward things like what you are doing) WPF is much superior to windows forms and GDI+.

This is how you could draw a moving arror in WPF/XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="blockArrow">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="500"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ed:BlockArrow x:Name="blockArrow" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="50" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="200"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I tried this.DoubleBuffered = true; but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: In that case we'll need more detail on how you actually draw the arrow and the other controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `PictureBox` try setting `DoubleBuffering = true`. If this flickering persists, draw everything onto a `Bitmap` before drawing the `Bitmap` on the screen.

Comment: I tried as ... 
Bitmap ArrowImage = Image.FromFile("D:\\Arrow.JPG");
Graphics grph = this.CreateGraphics();
grph.DrawImage(bitmapArrow, new Point(X, Y));

But its still flickering ...

Answer (score 0):

We do animation in WinForms and don't suffer from any flickering with our technique, which is something like this:

- Create a System.Windows.Forms.Timer object. Set the interval for 25 frames per second: `timer.Interval = 1000/25;` Add a callback method to the Tick event: `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(animateCallback)`
- `animateCallback` should update the coordinates of your Arrow instance and call Invalidate() to let the .NET graphics system call your control's Paint method.

Using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class is crucial to avoid flicker. This timer runs in the UI Thread. That means, the callback you get is in the UI Thread. So the system will not do any drawing while you are updating your arrow coordinates in your animateCallback method.