# Double buffering with Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, system.drawing, double-buffering

Double buffering the whole form can be done by setting the value of the "AllPaintingInWmPaint", "UserPaint" and "DoubleBuffer" ControlStyles to "true" (`this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true)`).

But this can't happen with a System.Windows.Forms.Panel because the class doesn't allow me to do so. I have found one solution: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267635-double-buffering-panel-control . I have also tried this: [Winforms Double Buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering) . It's laggy, even when it's used on a small drawing, I have some custom resources that I'm using in the form and other things because of which I won't turn the whole form into one drawing. And the second one seems to cause problems. Are there other ways to do that?

I'm asking this because I don't want the drawing on the panel to flash all the time when the form is being resized. If there is a way to get rid of the flashing without double buffering, I'll be happy to know.

Comment: I think it depends on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to perform refreshes of data or animation?  Are you trying to make a game?  I remember it being very difficult to remove flicker using system.drawing, even with double buffering (sometimes the frame rate is so slow that it looks like flicker even when double buffered)

Comment: It's a game that is played in a WinForms window. The drawing is drawn on a panel. The drawing is being changed when the user clicks on the panel. But when there are the scrolling and resizing processes, there is flickering too.

Comment: You can find a solution here, it worked for me.
[Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882921/c-sharp-panel-flickering-when-redrawing?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have posted my solution a long time ago...

Well, here is my solution:

```
Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);//set the size of the image
System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);//set the graphics to draw on the image
drawStuffWithGraphicsObject(gfx);//draw
pictureBox1.Image = buffer;//set the PictureBox's image to be the buffer
```

Makes me feel like a complete idiot for finding this solution years after asking this question.

I have tried this with a Panel, but it has proven to be slower when applying the new image. Somewhere I had read, that it is better to use Panel instead of PictureBox. I don't know if I have to add something to the code to speed things up for the Panel, though.

Answer (score 11):

Use a PictureBox if you don't need scrolling support, it is double-buffered by default.  Getting a double-buffered scrollable panel is easy enough:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyPanel : Panel {
    public MyPanel() {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }
}
```

The ResizeRedraw assignment suppresses a painting optimization for container controls.  You'll need this if you do any painting in the panel.  Without it, the painting smears when you resize the panel.

Double-buffering actually makes painting slower.  Which can have an effect on controls that are drawn later.  The hole they leave before being filled may be visible for a while, also perceived as flicker.  You'll find counter-measures against the effect in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls/2613272#2613272).

Comment: I can try to get rid of some controls, but they won't be many... I'll try making a new Panel class and "unlock" some of the System.Windows.Forms.Panel's features. But thanks for the link. This is a handy tutorial.

Comment: Hans, how do you exchange the old panel with this new one? I wrote this class, now how do I connect it to my existing `panel1` so it gets the aforementioned attributes?

Comment: Remove panel1 from your form and drop this one in its place.  You can rename it to "panel1" to keep existing code working.

Comment: I've tried that and I'm getting ambiguity errors between the "panel1'"s

Answer (score 1):

If acceptable you can stop refreshing the panel while resizing and enable it again after, this way you get rid of the ugly flickering.