# How to prevent controls from flickering when loading in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am currently facing a problem with my current windows application. This is the video of my problem.

[Flickering Problem](http://youtu.be/LBfJ1RWI4Q4)

As you can see, every time I click some buttons and when it loads the controls (tab controls and panel), they were flickering around and it seem to look annoying. How can I get rid of this? I already tried to set the `DoubleBuffer` to true but still not working. Any help?

I also do the suspendlayout() and resumelayout() inside the load event but still not working. Or maybe because I have coded it wrongly. This is my code:

```
Private Sub frmAdminPanel_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblUser.Text = currentUser
        Me.pnlOverview.SuspendLayout()
        Me.tabPayment.Visible = False
        Me.tabClientReporting.Visible = False
        Me.btnNewEntry.Visible = False
        Me.btnPayment.Visible = False
        setOverview()
        Me.pnlOverview.Visible = True
        Me.pnlOverview.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms Double Buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering)

Answer (score 0):

If there is any code in Load event of the form that manipulates the UI then you should try using SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() to prevent flickering.

Comment: I don't know why it was down voted. But I tried your suggestion. I updated my question.

Comment: can you try having the setoverview() after resumelayout()?

Comment: hmm ok.. can you try putting the suspend before the call of load?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`, try using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`.

Comment: Just replace `Me.pnlOverview.SuspendLayout()` with `Me.pnlOverview.BeginUpdate`. Same for `ResumeLayout`:  `Me.pnlOverview.EndUpdate()`