# Hide creation/initialation of form controls

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have several forms of which the containing controls are created and/or initialized at runtime. I do this in the Load event, but still, when the form is displayed, I can still see some forms being initialized.

In my understanding the Load event is happening before the form is displayed, so this shouldn't be a problem.

What am I missing here or what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: It is a common mistake is assume that a form that paints slowly because it has a lot of controls is busy "initializing".  Try minimizing and restoring it.

Comment: @Hans, What do you suggest to do in code? The form is initialized correctly; I just don't want to see it happening.

Comment: Create your items inside the constructor instead of load. Just like auto-generated code InitializeComponent() that's inside the Form constructor.

Comment: hmm maybe try `override void OnLoad` instead of using `Form_Load` event

Comment: At this point you should have mentioned what you saw when you minimized and restored your form.  If it still looks like it is "initializing" then you *know* that it has nothing to do with the Load event handler.  A trick to make painting less noticeable is available in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718648/17034).

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `this.SuspendLayout();` at the beginning of your **Load Event** and call `this.ResumeLayout();` in the last line of the **Load event**.

Answer (score 1):

Create your items inside the constructor instead of load. Just like auto-generated code `InitializeComponent()` that's inside the Form constructor, you can create instances of your controls and other objects after that line as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make form invisible in costructor and after your runtime initialization in `Load` event handler is completed show it.
Or you can try to override `OnLoad()` method in your custom form and put `base.OnLoad()` after your custom actions