# Anyway to remove text flickering in this custom ProgressBar class?

Tags: c#, text, progress-bar, flicker

This is what I made to have string displayed on the bar:

```
public class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
{
    const int WmPaint = 15;
    SizeF TextSize;
    PointF TextPos;

    public ProgressBarWithText()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.TextChanged += ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged;
        this.SizeChanged += ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged;
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set { base.Text = value; }
    }   

    void RecalcTextPos()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text))
            return;

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
        {
            TextSize = graphics.MeasureString(base.Text, this.Font);
            TextPos.X = (this.Width / 2) - (TextSize.Width / 2);
            TextPos.Y = (this.Height / 2) - (TextSize.Height / 2);
        }
    }

    void ProgressBarWithText_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecalcTextPos();
    }

    void ProgressBarWithText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecalcTextPos();
    }     

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WmPaint:
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                    graphics.DrawString(base.Text, base.Font, Brushes.Black, TextPos.X, TextPos.Y);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but the text only is flickering.
Turing **this.DoubleBuffered** to **true** doesn't helps.
Any other ideas? maybe I need to draw text at different message or different **Graphics**?

Comment: Why not just Override `OnPaint`? Is there any reason

Comment: I don't want to deal with drawing bar progress itself. Or else OnPaint simply never called.

Comment: This may help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323116

Comment: Thank you, but I will hope for some smaller solution to fix my code. Less code = less troubles to solve, this is what I think.

Comment: What is wrong with the link Sriram posted? It is straight forward and easy to implement.

Comment: There is some huge amount code. Look at the **terrybozzio** answer, this is easy, small and cool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms Double Buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place this CreateParams override in your class,it will sove it:

```
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                return result;
            }
        }
```