# How to reduce flickering when using Graphics.DrawString in C#, for a timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, flicker, text-rendering

Below is C# code that draws text on to a progress bar. It is used to add text to a progress bar, showing a remaining time count-down. I used the Graphics class to draw a string instead of a Windows Form label, as the label background could not be set to transparent when placed on a progress bar.

However, with this code, the text flickers every time it is updated (this method is called within a timer that ticks once each second), so it flickers pretty much constantly and is unusable as it stands.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Adds time remaining text into a System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target progress bar to add text into</param>
    /// <param name="remainingTimeText">The text to add into the progress bar.</param>
    private void set_progress_bar_text( System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar target, string remainingTimeText )
    {
        // Make sure we do not have a null progress bar.
        if( target == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Null Target" );
        }

        // Use the progress bar label font and size.
        Font textFont = new Font( labelProgress.Font.Name, labelProgress.Font.Size );

        // gr will be the graphics object we use to draw on the progress bar.
        using( Graphics gr = target.CreateGraphics() )
        {
            gr.DrawString( remainingTimeText,
                textFont,
                new SolidBrush( Color.Black ), // The brush we will use to draw the string, using a black colour.

                // The position on the progress bar to put the text.
                new PointF(
                // X location of text, to be placed at the centre of the progress bar.
                    progressBar.Width / 2 - ( gr.MeasureString( remainingTimeText,
                    textFont ).Width / 2.0F ),
                // Y Location
                progressBar.Height / 2 - ( gr.MeasureString( remainingTimeText,
                    textFont ).Height / 2.0F ) ) );
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting `DoubleBuffered = true` within this method as suggested by related questions on Stack Overflow, but it does not prevent the flickering. I can't reduce the amount of times the text is updated as the text is a countdown clock that must update once a second. Is there a way to prevent the flickering with double buffering, or are there any other potential solutions?

Comment: You should call set_progress_bar_text from inside the paint event of that progressbar and draw onto the graphics object thats given to you via the EventArgs. Then optimized Painting has a chance to work. Your timer should just trigger a repaint of the ProgressBar.

Comment: And also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418670/anyway-to-remove-text-flickering-in-this-custom-progressbar-class

Comment: The progress bar does not have a paint event of its own as far as I can tell  @Ralf.

Comment: Having looked at the other question, the solution there simply stops my text from showing up at all. CreateParams stops all text from being shown on the progress bar, is there some step that I am missing? Thanks @MatthewWatson

Comment: Well you have to do your painting inside the paint event, not like you are doing it just now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProgressBar seems to be one of those control that tries to hide painting. So we need to roll our own. Just exchange your ProgressBar with this one.

Added CreateParams override to reduce flicker as mentioned in the comments.

```
public class MyLovelyProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public MyLovelyProgressBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    private string foregroundText;
    public string ForegroundText 
    {
        get { return foregroundText;  }
        set 
        {
            if (foregroundText != value)
            {
                Invalidate();
                foregroundText = value;
            }
        } 
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
            result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
            return result;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 15: //WmPaint
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
                    PaintForeGroundText(graphics);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void PaintForeGroundText(Graphics graphics)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ForegroundText))
        {
            var size = graphics.MeasureString(ForegroundText, this.Font);
            var point = new PointF(Width / 2.0F - size.Width / 2.0F, Height / 2.0F - size.Height / 2.0F);
            graphics.DrawString(ForegroundText, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), point);
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply change ForegroundText of that ProgressBar in your Timer Event.

```
myLovelyProgressBar1.ForegroundText = "A constantly changing lovely text";
```

Comment: This is perfect to add text over a progress bar, but there is still a flickering issue unless the method used in  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418670/anyway-to-remove-text-flickering-in-this-custom-progressbar-class) is also used. Works perfectly now, thanks.

Comment: If you have the reputation then please edit my answer and add your change. If not are you talking about setting the WS_EX_COMPOSITED Style that helps?

Comment: I can't seem to edit the code you have added, but it is the WS_EX_COMPOSITED that is needed, as shown in this code: `protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                return result;
            }
        }`