# WinForms (.Net) VS VB6 Forms on Responsive

Tags: .net, winforms, performance, vb6

I have a client which has a Visual Basic 6 point of sale software system who I have pitched them would work better in .Net, but they refuse to make the change. 
Their argument is that a VB6 app is far more responsive and so far I can't disprove that to them. The VB6 app is lightning fast and on a CRT touch screen provides a really good user experience.

I have not yet been able to get .Net forms to perform like it yet...
Is there a method to improve the responsiveness? Will perhaps WPF be a better alternative to .Net Winforms?

Answer (score 3):

VB6 was made to perform well on ~1996 vintage hardware.  That took a trick or three, it notably uses window-less controls.  There was a price, VB6 controls are hard to customize and their look-and-feel pretty much set in stone.  You can tell a VB6 app from a hundred feet away.

Winforms changed that, every control is a window, even a simple one like a Label.  Several big advantages to doing it that way, the object model is very simple with the base object providing a lot of functionality that can be customized with very little code.  And very good wysiwyg designer support.  Which is also its big disadvantage, Winforms programmers tend to stuff a window with dozens if not hundreds of controls.  Very easy to do, the designer makes it simple.  There was a price, the dispatcher overhead is significant and most easily seen by it taking a while for all these windows to repaint themselves.  Visibly, giving the perception of a slow program.  The workaround [is simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718648/17034).

WPF went back to the VB6 approach and also uses window-less controls.  But with a significantly improved DirectX-based rendering engine and strong support for look-and-feel customization.  And a deep object model with a steep learning curve, the primary reason Winforms still is used.  Window-less controls are also available in Winforms from .NET 2.0 additions like the ToolStripItem classes and from component vendors like Telerik.

Comment: very informative explanation