# Adjusting Controls Position in Windows form Application

Tags: c#

I have developed Windows form application and every screen I have set in such a way that it will get opened as full screen by default.(Since this is business requirement.)When I run application, All controls are adjusting at proper position but it is taking little time in doing the same which is causing flickering kind of effect and hence bad visualisation.When I run application in normal window size, it has no issue in running but issue comes only when I make it full screen.Is there any solution to overcome this.

Thanks,
Mandar

Comment: Have you tried to use dubble buffering? does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using dubble buffering on the form and its controls.
This way the flicker should go away.
See:

[Winforms Double Buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering)