# Winforms Double Buffering turns off after minimizing form

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker, doublebuffered

I have a form which displays several graphics and in order to improve the visual experience while the graphics are rendered I have used [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718648/3599179) that enables Double Buffering.

When I execute the application without minimizing/maximizing the form, the Double Buffering works excellent, but if I happen to minimize the form and maximize it again, now the Double Buffering doesn't work anymore and the graphics get repainted with a visible flickering.

So is there a way to turn on Double Buffering every time the form gets minimized/maximized?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```cs
bool hasMinimized;
void SizeChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized ) {
        hasMinimized = true;
    } else {
        if ( hasMinimized ) {
            hasMinimized = false;
            /* Call SetStyle() in here */
        }
    }
}
```

you have to link Form's `SizeChanged` event to `SizeChangedCallback`.
like this:

```
this.SizeChanged += SizeChangedCallback;
```

Comment: This code only controls the `WindowState` property of the form, but doesn't do anything related with double buffering. Where and how should I call the `protected override CreateParams CreateParams` method in your code?

Comment: If you are asking about how to call `protected override CreateParams CreateParams`, your question is wrong.

`CreateParams` property is only accessed at once when form's creation.
To overriding `CreateParams`, open your Form's source code and type [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering/3718648#3718648)

or you can replace `/* Call SetStyle() in here */` to `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);`

Comment: hope this help to you

Comment: I followed all your instructions but nothing has changed at all with regard to the flickering.

Comment: Can you provide me a piece of code to prevent the flickering? (Form)

Comment: Double buffering with SetStyle is NOT the same as double buffering with CreateParams, in forms with many controls the create params solution is radically better